# A Tree that shakes off its Leaves

Tags: bones

I'm trying to create a very low poly, 2D tree that uses square pixels as leaves. I have animated the tree and I'm now adding leaves. I'd like to make the leaves shake with the tree's animation and then, gradually, fall off.

I've tried doing this by attaching an emitter to an armature, but I can't make the emitted objects follow the movement of the bones. Any advice on this? Maybe I have to do this through another method entirely.

[image: This is just a simple example, where the blue petals don't follow the morphing of the polygon emitter]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution that's pretty simple with the help of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPCs4XbGth8

Basically, create a controller particle system that manages other particles systems. Then create the first (1) particle system which keeps the leaves tracked onto the tree, using No 'Physics'. Then, create a second (2) particle system in the same position, which uses Newtonian physics and Brownian motion.

In the controller cube, the first key should be attached to (1) and second key should be attached to (2) and you can use timing to set how long you want the leaves to stay attached.

It's an alright start: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XArOF.jpg

One problem is, the leaves fall off all at once. The Brownian motion can hide this and make it look like some leaves stay attached for a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

In the Modifier panel of the emitter object, make sure the Armature modifier is **before** (above) the ParticleSystem modifier.

Comment: I understand this emits the particles in sync with the emitter's movement. But I want the particles, as they're falling, to maintain the movement of the emitter.